# How to reference Kivy App class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I stuck at a problem of referencing app class real variable ,
I am a beginner in kivy

see this code

```
class Screen_mgr(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def func(self):
        if(SimpleApp.num == 0): #this statement always returns True as num is always 0 in app class
            SimpleApp.num +=10 #How can I access the num variable of app class

class SimpleApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    num = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return Screen_mgr()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleApp().run()
```

**I want to use that num variable everywhere in python code only Not in KV code.**

Thanks For Reading .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code (at least what you posted of it) should work as you expect. Here is a version of your code, with additional code just to make it work. The `Button` calls the `func` every time you press it, and it shows the expected behavior (with `num` as a `NumericProperty`):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class Screen_mgr(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def func(self):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        print(app.num)
        if(app.num == 0): #this statement always returns True as num is always 0 in app class
            app.num +=10 #How can I access the num variable of app class


Builder.load_string('''
<Screen_mgr>:
    MainScreen:
        id: main
        name: 'main'
        Button:
            text: 'doit'
            on_release: main.func()
''')


class SimpleApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    num = NumericProperty(0)

    def build(self):
        return Screen_mgr()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleApp().run()
```

Comment: No Sir this will not change the real value of x in app class But it will change the value for an instance of it and only remain in that screen only its gonna be 0 if i create multiple screens

Comment: For example if i create another screen named ScreenTwo then the value of num when accessed by SimpleApp.num will be 0 for that screen.

Comment: The `num` is defined in your `App`, not in a `Screen`. Please post the code where you are accessing the `func()` method.

Comment: I Hope you understand my problem

Comment: I want to share the value of num to all screens

Comment: Sir that variable num is a NumericProperty.I updated it.

Comment: Using `NumericProperty` makes it a property of the `SimpleApp` instance, so you must access it using the instance of `SimpleApp` as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank You Sir I am sure this will fix my problem.It is midnight 12:00 AM in my country and i am going to sleep.Surely Update you if this works

Answer (score 1):

You can define it outside of your class that will make it a global variable so you can use it everywhere in your .py file or .kv file

Comment: Yes this is also a way but making a variable global will not update the variable on screen.I am sorry but i just updated the code.i declared variable num to be a NumericProperty.

Comment: did it helped to achieve to get what you want

Comment: Sorry to say but not helped me